Importing C libraries into Swift Framework
I have written some cryptography code built on top of OpenSSL, and added additional logic calling it in C functions and bridging to Swift to use in my iOS application. I have had no problems with getting this to work - but now I would like to extract this into my own framework/library so I can publicly distribute it.
I have tried importing this the same way as my iOS application was - but the only difference is I can't use a bridging header - and instead I need to use a module map and umbrella header. Inside my umbrella header though, when I try to build - I get: 'openssl/ec.h' file not found.
I've added OpenSSL to both pods.
The relevant code snippets from my framework:
modulemap:
framework module iOS_Reader_Library {
    umbrella header "../iOS_Reader_Library.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }

}

iOS_Reader_Library.h:
#ifndef iOS_Reader_Library_h
#define iOS_Reader_Library_h

#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

// List of functions here

/**
 * Generates an EC key pair using the P-256 curve
 * @param error Pointer to error message string, NULL if no error
 * @return EC_KEY pointer on success, NULL on failure
 */
EC_KEY *generate_ec_key_pair(char **error);



#endif /* iOS_Reader_Library_h */

And heres the equivalent from my working iOS app:
iOS-Bridging-Header.h
#import <openssl/bio.h>
#import <openssl/pem.h>
#import <openssl/ssl.h>
#import <openssl/err.h>
#import <openssl/evp.h>
#import <openssl/ec.h>
#import <openssl/ecdh.h>
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>


EC_KEY *generate_ec_key_pair(char **error);
unsigned char *get_compressed_public_key(EC_KEY *key, size_t *len, char **error);

If anyone know's what else I need to do to get this to work in my framework please let me know + I'm happy to provide more context if needed. I need to keep this closed source because we're working with external protocols that are under NDA
Thank you!!

would you consider making a Swift Package, rather than a Framework?

Thanks for the reply @topsig, because we use propriety algorithms, we'd rather keep this closed source and use a framework

To be honest, I wouldn't trust proprietary closed source cryptography.

I understand, but it's for our clients to decrypt specific types of messages. We're following protocols from big tech companies that we signed an NDA for. I just need to know if its possible :)
